# advanced search - code 1017 invalid where clause [Backendless]

Tags: curl, backendless

I have a table called `Request` with an entry with `requestId` `F92G3W`.

When I do
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X "GET" -v "https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Request?where=requestId%3DF92G3W"`

or `Request?where=requestId=F92G3W` (with equal sign)

I get the error `{"code":1017,"message":"Invalid where clause. Not Existing columns: F92G3W"}`.

But when I do the same curl with `https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Request`, I get back a list of results including the entry with `requestId` `F92G3W`.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: When I change the `requestId` to `1` and `GET -v  https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Request?where=requestId%3D1`, I get the correct object returned. So it may be a problem with values as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "requestId" column has the type of "STRING". As a result, the value in the query must be put in quotes:

```
  https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Request?where=requestId='F92G3W'
```

Comment: Hey Mark, forgot I posted this on here as well as Backendless support. Got it working, thanks again.